# PHP | join() an array with of single-itemed arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array(
    array('item 1'),
    array('item 2'),
    array('item 3'),
    array('item 4')
)
```

I want to use the `join()` function in PHP to create the following string:

```
item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4
```

Obviously, `join($items, ', ')` doesn't work (array to string conversation)

Is there a better way doing this besides looping through the array?

Comment: combine `join (implode)` and `array_map` functions.
Example: 
`implode(', ', array_map(function($item){return $item[0];}, $items));`

Comment: Thanks, should work.